# How to get a and b value from a text like axb?

Tags: c#, string

I am facing a problem with how to get a specific *string value* from a *text*. For example: for a given `string`

```
"400X500 abc"
```

How can I get some `string` from that text like:

```
string width = "400"
string height = "500"
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Best Regards,

Cherry Truong

Comment: You need to provide more details, some example code showing what you're trying to do because it's not clear.

Comment: Whats is `abc` in `400X500 abc`?

Comment: is the string in the same format all the time?

Comment: He probably want to split the string by "X" as delimiter. Shouldn't this question be closed as there is no search effort?

Comment: abc mean random text or some description for the specific type of structural beam in my case. For example : "400x500mm" . So I want to get specific string of width and height value of the structural beam from it label.

Comment: The name string of the structural might be in the same format all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions* in order to *extract* numbers

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 string source = "400X500 abc";

 string[] numbers = Regex
   .Matches(source, "[0-9]+") 
   .OfType<Match>()
   .Select(match => match.Value)
   .ToArray(); 

 string width = numbers.ElementAtOrDefault(0) ?? "";
 string height = numbers.ElementAtOrDefault(1) ?? "";
```

Or (if you want to be sure that `X` delimiter is present)

```
  Match match = Regex
    .Match(source, @"([0-9]+)\s*X\s*([0-9]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

  string width = match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : "";
  string height = match.Success ? match.Groups[2].Value : "";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the sharing code. It worked beautiful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
string data = "400X500 abc";
string[] splitData = data.TrimEnd('a', 'b', 'c').Trim().Split('X');
string width = splitData[0] ?? string.Empty;
string height = splitData[1] ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the input string is always in the same format.

"heightXwidth abc"

```
var value = "400X500 abc";

var vals = value.Trim().Split('X');

var height = new string(vals[0] == null ? "0".ToArray() : vals[0].Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
var width = new string(vals[1] == null ? "0".ToArray() : vals[1].Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

I'm sure you could adjust as needed.

**EDIT:**

I adjusted the code to avoid the issues as pointed out in the comments and ensure you only get the numbers from the string

Comment: yes, but in the original case it says the string is formatted as "400x500 abc", resulting in the not so different endresult of
var height = value.Split(' ')[0].Split('x')[0];
var width = value.Split(' ')[0].Split('x')[1];

Comment: In this case, `vala[1]` would also contain the postfix `abc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that it will always be in that format, you can do something like this:

```
string raw = "400X500";
string width = raw.Substring(0, raw.IndexOf("X"));
string height = raw.Substring(raw.IndexOf("X") + 1);
```

Now `width="400"` and `height=500`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text is always going to be in the format "100X200 aabdsafgds", then a working solution would look something like:

```
var value = "100X200 aabdsafgds";
var splitValues = value.Split(new[] { 'X', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var value1 = splitValues[0];
var value2 = splitValues[1];
```

Comment: No, in that case you would need to use regex like Dmitry showed.